# inital connection to TFS very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We're running TFS 2010 on a dedicated machine. The SQL db is also running on the same machine so there is no external LAN/WAN access there.

When we check in/out or get anything from TFS - the initial connection and any connections after some inactivity from VS is extremely slow, sometimes up to 1 or 2 minutes. Once it does whatever it has to do, things start run fast and move along with no problems whatsoever.

What/where should i check to find this bottleneck, or whatever it is that's turning off after inactivity ?

Comment: Do you have an internet proxy at your location?  Sometimes proxy lookup can cause TFS connections to be slow.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue, potentially DNS related.  Any chance you can run a network trace and see what is happening on the wire? It might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @RichardBanks - i've tried using the IP of the server instead of DNS name. same problem.

Comment: To add on to what Ed Blankeship said below-- is your TFS infrequently used?  If so, the ASP.NET Worker Process may be getting swapped out due to being idle.  On some machines, it can take a noticeable amount of time for that process to wake up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is similar to SQL Server Reporting services. When it is inactive for some time (20 min?) the worker process fall asleep and wake up time is rather long.
 [SSRS 2008 - Long delay after a period if inactivity](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/d14aebe3-40b8-444d-bfac-b62b27543936), [How to Speed up MS SQL Server Reporting Services SSRS on First Run](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2197/how-to-speed-up-ms-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-on-first-run/). There should be similar setting for TFS webservices.

Comment: I've try this solution but it still very slow! Any others?

Comment: The original question is about initial connection. To me it seems that TFS is slow all the time. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is the traditional ASP.NET wakeup pipeline that you are running into.  If you want to try out setting a scheduled task that runs `PingTFS.exe` then it will keep the site loaded so that you don't see this initial hit each time the TFS web services have cooled down.

- You can find `PingTFS.exe` available from Neno Loje here:  https://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/03/02/how-to-ping-tfs-to-see-if-it-s-up-and-running.aspx

If that doesn't help, then it's likely the hardware in the environment.  You definitely don't want to have too few of resources for your TFS environment.  Let us know if the first suggestion doesn't work out.

Comment: It is quite the resource hog isn't it? I have the 11 beta of tfs running on an 8gig i5 powered laptop running Server 2008 and that is below the recommended specification. TeamForge runs happily on a 1gig virtual machine...

Comment: Actually TFS isn't a big resource hog. Since it is fully web based on the app server side, it doesn't take up resources until the services are called

Comment: TFS 2010 and TFS "11" Beta only have a 10 GB RAM minimum when you are also having SharePoint 2010 Server or SharePoint 2010 Foundation on the application tier.  It's the SharePoint piece that causes the memory requirements.  SharePoint is optional though.  For a production TFS environment in a team setting, it's just not something you want to be frugal with.  TFS does a lot more than what most people think about.

Comment: I use PingTFS and see "Respone Received. TFS is up and running". I back to VS 2010 and it's still very slow to open an work item! After that, I open another work item and it's so fast! It very slow for the first time only!!!